# Why angular2 declare interface in this way?

Tags: typescript

I found following interface definition in `angular2/src/core/di/decorators.ts`

```
export interface InjectFactory {
    (token: any): any;
    new (token: any): InjectMetadata;
}
```

I am wondering what is this supposed to do? Why declaring an interface as either a `function` or `class`?(BTW, i know what `interface` mean. I just don't know why in both `function` and `new constructor`)

Is there any reason behind it, why this is a good to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following section in typescript specification [object types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#13-object-types) has a nice explanation using JQuery as a sample of why this might come in handy

You might want/need to use object that implements the above interface both as a function or as a regular object. Below is sample from the above link that illustrates such jquery object '$':

```
$.get("http://example.com",  
  function (data: string) {  
      $("div").text(data);  
  }  
);
```

Note usage of $.get() and $("div").

Such interfaces allows us to describe existing javascript objects that does not fit nicely into typescript object/class paradigm.